# how to send hayageek jquery plugin form with an empty file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, upload

I want create a form with an upload system.

the best Jquery plugin I found for my work is [hayageek](http://hayageek.com/).

I create a form like this:

```
<form>
<inpu type="text" id="title" name="title" value="">
<div class="col-submit">
<div id="fileuploader">Upload</div>
<button id="extrabutton" class="submitbtn">send</button>
</div>
</form>
```

And jquery code:

```
var extraObj = $("#formdata2").uploadFile({
url:"upload.php",
fileName:"myfile",
dynamicFormData: function()
{
    var data ={ title:$('#title').val()}
    return data;
}
});
```

And send form  with click:

```
$("#extrabutton").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault(); 
        extraObj.startUpload();
    });
```

It works normally when I attach a file to form.
But with no file it dosen't work.(not sent $_POST to upload.php)

My form has not file always!

Please tel me a trick to send form without a file too.

I try this but not work...

```
$("#extrabutton").click(function(event){
            if(!event.preventDefault())
            alert('send form without file');
});
```